# How to set selection in spinner with SimpleAdapter?

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner, simpleadapter

I am populating spinner from below code and its working perfect. When user select any value from spinner then I am saving stateCodeId in sqlite. Now what I want that when user come again then I want to show the seleted value from ID which already saved in sqlite. How can I show value selected in spinner ?

```
public void fillStateData() {
        try {
            State_data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
            State_data.clear();
            Cursor cursor_State = db.rawQuery("SELECT nSerialNo as _id,cCodeName FROM CodeMaster where nCtgId = 6", null);

            int i = 0;
            if (cursor_State.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Map<String, String> datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    if (i == 0) {
                        datanum.put("nStateID", "0");
                        datanum.put("cStateName", "Select State");
                        State_data.add(datanum);

                        datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        datanum.put("nStateID", cursor_State.getString(0));
                        datanum.put("cStateName", cursor_State.getString(1));
                        State_data.add(datanum);
                    } else {
                        datanum.put("nStateID", cursor_State.getString(0));
                        datanum.put("cStateName", cursor_State.getString(1));
                        State_data.add(datanum);
                    }
                    i += 1;
                } while (cursor_State.moveToNext());

            }
            String[] fromwhere = {"nStateID", "cStateName"};
            int[] viewswhere = {R.id.txtnStateID, R.id.txtcStateName};
            StateAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), State_data, R.layout.state_list_template, fromwhere, viewswhere);
            spnState.setAdapter(StateAdapter);
            cursor_State.close();
            spnState.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    TextView stateId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtnStateID);
                    stateCodeId = stateId.getText().toString();

                    fillDistrictData(stateCodeId);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

Like this I am getting ID from sqlite.

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT nStateId from MemberMaster where nCustID ="+SesPMbrID+"", null);

        c.moveToFirst();
        String state = c.getString(0);
```

Comment: First you have to get ID from the DB and then match ID from DB to list of all IDs. At last, when you find ID in list, note that position and user spinner.setSelectio(position); to set spinner on store DB ID.

Comment: I am getting this error - java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 9, size is 5

Comment: It means your DB contains 5 ID and you are searching for 9, which is not in list.

Comment: I have 5 items in my list. Now what happening that I have custom layout for my spinner which have two text view. One for id and second for name. I give visiblity gone to textview which store id.

Comment: 9 also coming from sqlite which is id of any item. I want to show name which id is 9

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
spinner.setSelection(position);
```

Comment: Thanks Francois L. I am populating Two columns from sqlite. ID Column is hide and only names are showing. I am saving id in sqlite and again retrieve saved id. Now i want to show selected item from id.